# Time and date condition logic statement MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a logic where I `SELECT` from my database only rows that have not expired yet. So anything that is greater than `NOW()` will now show up.

Here is a modified version of a code:

```
include_once('Database.php');

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
        format_time FROM table WHERE format_time > NOW()");
    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
```

My `format_time` data is saved as `TIMESTAMP` in format of `2018-05-13 23:30:00` (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

For some reason I am still retrieveing my data even after the expire date.

Comment: I think it could be a local time issue. Is your project running in local (XAMPP, WAMP, ...) or in a live server?

Comment: Please try to run query to check your current set timezone in your mysql

`select NOW()`;

And then compare your timestamp value in DB and current time from (select now()) query.

Comment: I am not sure, it is weird bug I got. I just dropped the database, and recreated the table again. And it started working. Which is quite weird. And for NOW() is fetching my timezone. So I am still wondering how can I replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here what I've done. I went in phpMyAdmin and dropped the `event_table`. And then I recreated the data again, putting the same exact information. Then the query started running normal again, and meeting the conditions. Now this might be a minor bug, and I am too unsure how to replicate this bug again. However everything is working the way I expect.

For those who are going to view the post in the future, you might not want to make your data disappear immediately, so I added additional operation:

`SELECT col1, col2, col3, format_time FROM event_table WHERE format_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY format_time ASC`

This query will ensure that the data will only be removed after an hour, when the condition is met.